# Best way to View Powerpoint Presentations on Ipad

Tags: ipad, applications, keynote, ms-office

I'm not a big ipad user, but I need ot know how to view powerpoint presentations on an ipad. I have noticed alot of people mentioned to convert it to a video, pdf slides or image slides. But I have also noticed that KeyNote seems to do alot of the same stuff as powerpoint.

Is KeyNote the best way and will it allow editing too? What drawbacks are there? What is your suggestion for powerpoint on ipad?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking just to view, you can convert your slides to PDF and use iBooks.  If you also want editing capabilities, Keynote is indeed the best way to view and edit slideshows on the iPad. it carries the advantage of being tailored for your device. Keynote is Apple's version of PowerPoint, so it can edit and view slideshows. Just so you know, you won't achieve 100% compatibility with PowerPoint, but it will be pretty good. I use Keynote and I'm continually surprised by it's abilities and it's depth. I say, go with keynote.

Answer (score 1):

I think [GoodReader](http://goodreader.ne) (I believe it is $5.99) is great for storing and viewing not just PowerPoint presentations, but just about any type of file. It can open huge PDFs without crashing. 
But make sure you get the iPad version, otherwise you can't view the app in full screen.

Or, you can jailbreak your device and install SBSettings, lighttpd, lighttpd SBSettings Toggle and iFile from Cydia. Slide from left to right on your status bar (where the time is on your iPad) and press More, Toggles, then turn on the toggle called "lighttpd" and press your Home button. Now open iFile and use it to copy your presentations to /var/www. Open SBSettings and tap Lighttpd to turn off the server and save battery power.

But the only way to edit presentations that's worth buying is Keynote, I believe.

Ad@m

Answer (score 0):

There's an online "Office" tool called "QuickOffice", that appears to allow you to essentially create and use PowerPoints:

**http://www.quickoffice.com/quickoffice_pro_hd_ipad/**

Answer (score 0):

To retain Powerpoint dynamic content (animation, fonts, hyperlink...) you need to convert to HTML5. SlideGo has free tool to do that. You can then view it online with mobile safari. To view offline you can use the same site to export to Epub which still retain interactivity when view on iBooks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Hong Nguyen! Can you please add a link to the software you mention in your answer? It is always helpful to add a link to help the OP to find the right software. Thank you.